# Any reasons why my UIView does not change if I set different constrains?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an UIView inside my normal UIView. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(canvasUnder.frame.origin.y)
    let getRelativePosition = view.frame.size.height * 0.25
    canvasUnder.frame.origin.y = canvasUnder.frame.origin.y + getRelativePosition
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    print(canvasUnder.frame.origin.y)
    print(getRelativePosition)
}
```

It does however stays at the original position. This is my print:

```
240.0
320.0
80.0
```

How can this be? Thank  you. edit: this is what I want: My UIView that I want to change has a height of * 0.25 of the root view. I want that my UIView is right off the boundaries of my root view, so it needs to be 25% of the root views height, followed by a constrained movement that will push my UIView down.

Edit 2: I managed to to this,  this way:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("called")
    let getRelativePosition = view.frame.size.height * 0.25
        self.CanvasUnder.frame.origin.y = self.CanvasUnder.frame.origin.y + getRelativePosition
}
```

However this method get called each and every time something changed. I just want that my canvasUnder is just right off the screen when the view is presented. Then, whenever I want, I want to animate that UIView to pop up. I want to use this code:

```
        let getRelativePosition = view.frame.size.height * 0.25
        self.CanvasUnder.frame.origin.y = self.CanvasUnder.frame.origin.y - getRelativePosition
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
```

Or putting the change of frame inside the animate function will not work. It just keeps triggering the viewDidLayoutSubviews method which will hide again my UIView.

So how can I just hide that view right under my root view, and pop it up with an slide up animation which will take 1 second?

Comment: You're not using actual constraints so, if the view depends on them for its layout, your frame adjustments may be ignored.

Comment: I updated my question, how can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you want your 25% view to "squeeze" the existing view as it slides up? Or, do you want it to slide up on-top-of (covering) the bottom portion of the existing view? And, do you want it to slide in-and-out via a button tap? Or some other trigger?

Comment: When the View is presented, the UIView inside of it needs to be hidden. The UIView is 25% of the View's height, so pushing the UIView 25% relative the the View's height will do that trick. When the View is loaded, I want to make a UIButton's action where I can bring back up my UIView with a slide in animation. It does not have the squeeze, just bring the UIView up. Thank you!

Comment: See my edits in my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "this is what I want: My UIView that I want to change has a height of
>   * 0.25 of the root view. I want that my UIView is right off the boundaries of my root view, so it needs to be 25% of the root views
>   height, followed by a constrained movement that will push my UIView
>   down."

This is exactly what auto layout and constraints are for, so you don't have to constantly be calculating sizes.

Use constraints to "pin" your view to left, right and bottom of its superview, then set it's Height Equal to Superview Height, with a multiplier (ratio) of 1:4

That will keep its height at 25% of the "root view" and will keep it "stuck" to the bottom.

[image]

<s>No code needed :)</s>

To animate the view in-and-out, add an IBOutlet to the Bottom constraint, and use this code...

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var trayBottomView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trayBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // hide the "tray" view
        trayBottomView.isHidden = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // constraints and frame sizes are fully calculated by AutoLayout here, so...

        // move the tray offscreen (below the view), and "un-hide" it
        self.trayBottomConstraint.constant = -self.trayBottomView.frame.height
        self.trayBottomView.isHidden = false

        // this first part will just put the tray view into position, below the screen
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

            // now, set the tray Bottom constraint to 0, so it will end up "sitting" on the bottom of the screen
            self.trayBottomConstraint.constant = 0

            // animate it into view - use delay to "wait a bit" before sliding the view up
            // duration of 0.75 (3/4 of a second) may be too slow, just tweak as desired

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: nil)

        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // if the tray Bottom Constraint is Zero, that means it is visible, so
        // set it to -(its own height) to position it offscreen, below the view
        // otherwise, it is already offscreen, so set it to Zero to bring it back up

        if self.trayBottomConstraint.constant == 0 {
            self.trayBottomConstraint.constant = -self.trayBottomView.frame.height
        } else {
            self.trayBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        }

        // animate it in or out of view
        // duration of 0.75 (3/4 of a second) may be too slow, just tweak as desired

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I already did set my UIView to be 25% of my root view. I just want it to hide when the view is presented, and I want to pop it up whenever I want. I updated my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In the future, you might want to ask your actual question to begin with. A little more likely to get the right answer.

Comment: Aah thank you a million times to help a fellow noob out of trouble :) you should earn a medal!

Answer (score 1):

> Any reasons why my UIView does not change if I set different constraints?

You are *not* changing constraints. You are saying `canvasUnder.frame.origin.y`. That is not a change of constraint. It is a change of `frame`. But you *cannot* directly change the frame if the view is positioned by constraints! The constraints are what positions the view, not the frame.

> How can this be?

Because you change the frame, and it does change just at that little moment. But by the time you *see* the view, the constraints have changed it back again!

Answer (score 0):

When you call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() it is triggering your view to relayout. It is being moved either by auto layout, or layout code in your  viewWillLayoutSubviews/viewDidLayoutSubviews functions.

Rather then updating the frame directly, either update the constraint, eg:

```
canvasUnderHeightConstraint.constant = view.frame.size.height * 0.25
```

Or, a better solution would be to use the multiplier field of the constraint to get your desired result.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                   attribute: .height,
                   relatedBy: .equal,
                   toItem: canvasUnder,
                   attribute: .height,
                   multiplier: 0.25,
                   constant: 0)
```

Comment: But I need to make changes all the time in my code, should I constantly asking those functions to make sure the constrains are updated?